# Wrong php version in VS Code

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code

I have php 7 on my computer and I am working on a symfony project using docker with php 8.
My VSCode doesn't recognize php version used in docker, it only recognizes php version installed on my computer.
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Remote Containers extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers). With that you can code directly on the container and thus use the PHP CLI version in your container.

Mind you: that cli version might differ also from the version that your webserver uses. So check that cli version on your container too.

Comment: I installed the extension and it works ! Thank you ! :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

So by default, VScode will use the target environment (your local machine) to pull information and develop against. If you want to use a development container for this (pros/cons for each). Then I would suggest you look over the https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers page.

Essentially you will need both docker engine and the target environment container defined.

Comment: You beat me to it :-P

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I installed the extension, my problem is fixed :)